# How to extract string before pattern in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable which has contents like this

line 1
   line 2
   line 3
   ======
   line 4
   line 5
   line 6
   ======
   .........
   line n
   ======

Now i want to extract lines before all occurence of '======' pattern and i want to assign it to each variable.
Expected output
    Var1=line 1
line 2
line 3
    Var2=line 4
line 5
line 6
    ...........
    Var_n=line n

Storing it in an array is also accepted
How to do it?

Comment: how you initialized your variable with this data? can you show it?

Comment: @Jayesh I used var+="$(<file.txt)",var+="======" to get lines of text from different files

Comment: Use same logic for different variables like `var1+="$(<file1.txt)",var2+="$(<file2.txt)",var3+="$(<file3.txt)",.....`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# original string
str="some lines1 ====== some lines2 ======"

# parse the string
v1="${str%% =*}"  # beginning at right, remove all to ' ='
tmp="${str% =*}"  # beginning at right, remove first occurrence of ' =*'
v2="${tmp##*= }"  # beginning at left,  remove all to '= '

# print the string and variable
echo "str: $str"
echo " v1: $v1"
echo " v2: $v2"

exit 0
```

output:

```
$ bash somelines.sh
str: some lines1 ====== some lines2 ======
 v1: some lines1
 v2: some lines2
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting parameter expansion. Just a side note: Word splitting/globbing is not performed on expansions in (non-array) assignments, so the quotes are not needed. `v1=${str%% =*}` etc. is just fine.

Comment: What part isn't working? I have the string you specified and it is broken into v1 and v2 as you also specified, so what part do you contend "doesn't work?"

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth thank you for that clarification. I've been beaten up so many times with "quote you variables", I do it largely out of habit now. The non-splitting with expansion is good to know.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve using parameter expansion as like

```
str="mystring:yourstring"  //here assume ":" is pattern
var=${str%:*}
echo $var
```

For your information you can use `#` instead `%` to get string after pattern

```
var=${str#*:}
```

Comment: this is not the answer i have expected..try to understand my edited question

Comment: @kumaran Have answered it about 5 hours ago and you edited question ( just 3 min ago ) totally with different requirement!! how can you say it's not!!. learn first how to ask question first. after 5 hour you realize it's not your answer. But i say you asked question wrongly and i answered that question correctly. See up votig .